# Use PullToRefreshExpandableListView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, pull-to-refresh

I used library for list view pull to refresh in Fragment and it is very good library : 
https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

Now I want to use **PullToRefreshExpandableListView** . I looked sample code, and explained very well on activity. Now I want to use it in Fragment. But I have problem. Below I write some parts code in Activity which done by library publisher, and my codes for Fragment

Original code for to use `PullToRefreshExpandableListView` in Activity :

```
class PullToRefreshExpandableListActivity extends
        ExpandableListActivity {

    //created mAdapter (SimpleExpandableListAdapter)
    //inflated mPullRefreshListView (PullToRefreshExpandableListView)
    //and setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

All ok !

and in my code

Fragment class created , **onCreateView** method inflated PullToRefreshExpandableListView , created mAdapter as above code. 
But when I want to set adapter , there is my problem :(

Code :

```
mPullRefreshListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Compile Error :

```
The method setAdapter(ListAdapter) in the type PullToRefreshAdapterViewBase<ExpandableListView> is not applicable for the arguments (SimpleExpandableListAdapter)
```

So if you know how to use `PullToRefreshExpandableListView` in Fragment, please help, or please write how to set adapter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use PullToRefreshExpandableListFragment:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/extras/PullToRefreshListFragment/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/extras/listfragment/PullToRefreshExpandableListFragment.java

Comment: How do you use that? do you extend ListFragment from the main fragment ?